# android finding parent instance in child activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a list of activity

```
   A -> B -> C -> D 

( A -> B means Activity A is calling B)
```

Now in this flow,Activity  C can also call B so one possibility may be `B -> C -> B -> C ....`

For calling 1 activity to another I am using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP so that I can get Control on flow. but my problem is i want to find instance of Activity A in C.

I am using getParent().getParent() to find Activity A but if i do this, i am going to stuck in the following scenario

```
B -> C -> B -> C
```

so how can i find instance of A in Activity C.

Answer (score 0):

to pass data from one activity to other , use intent (putExtra/getExtra) . pass reference of activity outside will also pass the context which will keep the screen alive always , so app will face memory and contextLeav issue .

so i will suggest to tgo with intent and ask if stuck somewhere .

Comment: actually in C, i want to call a method of A.

Comment: code which is usable in more then one activity , create separate class for them and use objects  . share data using intent or persistent storage . share code for more help

Comment: i cant separate this method because it need tabactivity instance only and A is tabactivity.